# How can you reload a Div like reloading a page, without calling another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Div and it has data called from php with a While loop.  I want my site to use less bandwidth with reloads for a faster user experience.  How would you with JQuery AJAX do something similar to a window.location.reload(); but only reload a div without calling another page?

```
<div ID="Results1"> 
    //While loop table in here (with rows of data), just needs to be reloaded, not entire page
</div>
```

Comment: You would first need to setup an endpoint (presumably a PHP file) that you can request which will respond with the data needed for that div.  Then you can use `jQuery.get()` to request that url and populate the div.

Comment: $.get( "test.php" );  I used this but nothing comes from my While loop

Comment: Not sure I understand, what while loop?  This should not be inside a while loop, unless you want to request `test.php` on each iteration...What does `test.php` respond with?  Be sure to read the documentation on `$.get` to understand what it does/how it works https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: I call a table of data that will be refreshed when I click a submit button.  I was just trying to have on the fly data coming back with a Div table refresh

Comment: If I understand your objective, then you'll want to make a single client side request with `$.get('test.php')` and then write the response of that url in your table with javascript, assuming the response from `test.php` is html.